bash and find: how to modify a path name from the lowest level up
I run the following command to recursively rid folders of characters that pose problems with certain apps, scripts, or on NFS/SMB, i.e., change ' to ’, ? to ？ (chinese char), : to ： (chinese char), etc.
$ find . -type d -execdir /usr/local/bin/rename "s/'/’/g" '{}' +
(rename is Aristotle Pagaltzis's perl script)
The issue is that if a given path has two or more occurrences of the above characters in two different levels, it fails to make the modification the second time as the initial path does not exist anymore, e.g., in /data/videos/john's pics/folder/last year's bday/folder/, it fails with No such file or directory. due to it having two '.
I'm thinking of running the above find command recursively from bottom up, but I do not know how to go about it and whether it is the best approach.
Using find or any other nix scripts/tools such as awk, etc., is fine by me.

Assuming GNU findutils, use the -depth option of 'find' to have it output subdirectories before the parent directory.

Yes... indeed, find . -depth -type d -execdir /usr/local/bin/_rename "s/'/’/g" '{}' + works beautifully. Thanks!
